# using GM_config in greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

for some ungodly reason i am using

```
// @require https://github.com/sizzlemctwizzle/GM_config/raw/master/gm_config.js
```

I am trying to use this. when i say:

```
   alert(typeof GM_config)
```

i get undefined. how in gods name do i include something to use in gm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Required scripts](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) will only download when you install the script. You probably added the line containing `@require` after creating the script. In that case it will never download.

The solution is to backup your script to a different location on your hardddisk. Remove the script in greasemonkey. Open the backup file in firefox, and install the script again. When you look in the gm_scripts directory of your profile you will see the gm_config.js has been downloaded in the same directory as your script.

Comment: What if "require" script updates. Will it be downloaded to replce old version?

Comment: [since Greasemonkey 0.9.0](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require), if Greasemonkey detects that the `@require` value(s) have been altered, these new values will be used (thus each `@require` shall be re-downloaded)

Comment: @Hooch, as far as I know, greasemonkey does not check if the script is updated. It will be downloaded just once.